# Receiving an "Error: expected an identifier" on C++ for "=="

Tags: c++, error-handling, filestream, fileinputstream

Im receiving an error on the " if (f_in); std::ifstream == int NULL);" code, where the "==" is underlines as the error and is saying "Error: expected as an identifier". I'm not sure on what to do and I am stuck :/. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>     // For cin/cout
#include <fstream>      // For file stream objects (ifstream)
#include <string>       // For the string data object

using namespace std;

int main()
{

   ifstream f_in;   // Creat an object for an 'input' file stream
   string       data;   // An object to hold our data read in form the file


  )

f_in.open("InputData.txt"); 

if (f_in); std::ifstream == int NULL); {
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file in.list!\n");
    exit(1);
}


f_in >> data;
cout << "First data item from file is: ' " << data << endl;

f_in >> data;
cout << "Second data item from file is: ' " << data << endl;

getline(f_in, data);
cout << "Line from file is: '" << data << endl;

getline(f_in, data);
cout << "Next line from file is: '" << data << endl;

// We are finished with the file. We need to close it.
f_in.close();

cout << "Finished!\n";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `)` after `string data;` supposed to do? Also your if statement is definitely wrong (not sure what do you want to achieve).

Comment: This: `if (f_in); std::ifstream == int NULL); {` is NOT C++! I understand what you are trying to accomplish with `if (f_in);` but what are you trying to accomplish with `std::ifstream == int NULL);` This just has no sense...

Comment: The answer to your question is: Read a C++ beginner's guide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (f_in); std::ifstream == int NULL);
```

You could rewrite this as this:

```
if (f_in)
    ;
std::ifstream == int NULL);
```

And you can see that this doesn't really make sense.

Maybe you meant:

```
if (!f_in) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file in.list!\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Or

```
if (f_in == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file in.list!\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much, yes I wrote the code in a confusing way but it makes perfect sense where I went wrong :) Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

you could rewrite the statement as

```
if (f_in); // actually do nothing if the condition is true
std::ifstream == int NULL); { // starts like a variable declaration
```

that's why the compiler expects an identifier.
Next you've another pending error with int NULL (type value).
You probably want to write something like:

```
if (f_in.is_open())
```

see ifstream ref: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/